# What is this thing called "LCD interface" found in MCU datasheets?

Tags: microcontroller, lcd

When browsing ARM MCU datasheets I often find a thing called an "LCD Controller" or "LCD Interface" and I'm wondering what it is and how it works. 
It's present on the LPC3130[[link](http://www.newark.com/nxp/lpc3130fet180-551/mcu-32bit-arm9-180mhz-tfbga-180/dp/70R5680)|[datasheet]](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1643185.pdf/) and referred to as "Integrated 4/8/16-bit 6800/8080 compatible LCD interface"
I think it's a sort of controller for common bus used in Displays.
Questions:
1.What is the "pinout" of the bus? What do the lines transmit? I want to now how this works.
2.What sort of LCD is this able to control? Graphic? Alphanumeric?
3.Does this mean the MCU has an built in GPU inside to control the Graphics?

Comment: Liquid Crystal Display

Comment: Data sheet section 9.1 has timing diagrams. Looks to me like in "6800 mode" (RW strobed by E, instead of "8080 mode" separate RD and WR strobes) it can drive an HD44780 character-based LCD controller. It's more like an old-style microcontroller bus, not a graphics controller.

Comment: See application note http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10880.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this one looks like a parallel I/O port designed for talking to COG (chip-on-glass) LCD panels

1. 4-16 parallel data and 2 handshaling lines
2. graphic panel with (chip-on-glass) or alphanumeric panel
3. no. these types of panel are persistent and don't need refresh, if you you want graphics you will have tp place every pixel.